# What does "karateca" mean in Spanish?

Tags: definiciones

What does the Spanish slang word ***karateca*** mean? I've already tried to look at other sites however they do not know either.

Comment: Google is your friend! https://www.google.es/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gLs_WMvgLqrD8gfz7YiIDQ#q=karateca

Comment: Hey Mickey, did you do some research before? Why do you think this is slang? Please do have a read to [ask].

Comment: I guess you already know that a _karateca_ is someone who practises karate, maybe you read it in a context that made no literal sense? If possible, provide some more info.

Answer (score 6):

The Diccionario de la Lengua Española available [**here**](http://www.rae.es/) defines [**karateca**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Mg7ESDy) as

> 1. m. y f. Persona que practica el kárate.

Alternatively, online Spanish-English dictionaries like [**reverso**](http://dictionary.reverso.net/spanish-english/) translate [**karateca**](http://dictionary.reverso.net/spanish-english/karateca) as

> 1) karate expert (m)
>   2) karate expert (f)

No slang here - just look at a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Person who practices karate, no matter what style or skill level.

Answer (score 2):

Argentinian here. It might be figurative speaking, in Spanish it's used a lot. We usually use those words to point out certain characteristics of a person's behavior or looks.

For example: a person who likes to fight and does so in a weird looking manner we could call him a "karateca" because he moves like he is practicing a martial art. (We tend to pigeon-hole a lot too).

Another example: Here in Argentina we use the word "ninja" referring to those characteristics, we could also use the word "ninja" to talk about a person who has Asian-looking face when he is clearly not an Asian descendant.